# I can't recover elements from a Soap Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I need your help again, I'm trying to recover some elements from a Soap response and I'm stuck.

This is how I try to do the response:

```
   using(new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                SoapAuthenticationHeader.Create(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName, client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password);

                zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList.Customerid = cuit;

                ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse1 zWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse1 = await client.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListAsync(zWsCustomerInvoiceGetList);

            }
```

And this `SoapAuthenticationHeader.Create()` public void so I send basic authentication as headers:

```
public static void Create(string username, string password)
    {
        string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
    }
```

Using this, the response only brings empty elements (I don't know why I can't post the image):

[Empty elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqNv.png)

After this, I thought it was because I was not using the `await client.OpenAsync();` of Reference.cs, but if I do the OpenAsync method I have this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[ServiceReference1.Z_WS_CUSTOMER_INVOICE_GET_LIST], cannot be modified while Opened state.'

I'm sorry if this is a noob question but I can't figure it out what to do. Maybe I have to send all the XML elements empty to have a response?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is my Reference.cs:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style")]
[DataContract]
public partial class ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList
{
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    private string customeridField;
    
    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    private string pedidoCliField;
    
    [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    private string pedidoSapField;

    [XmlElement(Order = 4)]
    private ZfacturaMat[] tFacturaMatField;

    [XmlElement(Order = 5)]
    public List<ZfacturaMat> zfacturaMats;

    [XmlElement(Order = 6)]
    private ZinvoiceList[] tInvoicesField;

    [XmlElement(Order = 7)]
    public List<ZinvoiceList> invoicesField;

    [XmlElement(Order = 8)]
    private Bapiret1[] tReturnField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string Customerid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customeridField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.customeridField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string PedidoCli
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pedidoCliField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pedidoCliField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
    public string PedidoSap
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pedidoSapField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pedidoSapField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public ZfacturaMat[] TFacturaMat
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tFacturaMatField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tFacturaMatField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public ZinvoiceList[] TInvoices
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tInvoicesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tInvoicesField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=5)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public Bapiret1[] TReturn
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tReturnField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tReturnField = value;
        }
    }
}

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListRequest
{
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style", Order=0)]
    public ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList;
    
    public ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListRequest()
    {
    }
    
    public ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListRequest(ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList)
    {
        this.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList = ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList;
    }
}


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse1
{
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style", Order=0)]
    public ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse;
    
    public ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse1()
    {
    }
    
    public ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse1(ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse)
    {
        this.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse = ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse;
    }
}

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListResponse1> ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListAsync(ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList)
    {
        ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListRequest inValue = new ServiceReference1.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListRequest();
        inValue.ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList = ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetList;
        return await((ServiceReference1.Z_WS_CUSTOMER_INVOICE_GET_LIST)(this)).ZWsCustomerInvoiceGetListAsync(inValue);
    }
```

Comment: The response only brings empty elements may be a namespace issue, you can check the answers provided by these two posts.https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247367/17218587 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34455484/17218587

Comment: The exception(cannot be modified while Opened state) might be that the internal ChannelFactory is already in the Created/Opened state and when you try to open the proxy, it is calling the Open method of the channel factory which throws an invalid operation exception.https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550715/17218587

Comment: After seeing this answers, I continue without being able to do the response. I did the Order and Namespaces but I can't do it, there is not a particular error, Is just I have a null response like the picture